# Tumblr API get current AVATAR URL

Tags: tumblr

Everyone knows? about avatar url in tumblr api / read / json?
like for example the facebook?

http://graph.facebook.com/[your facebook id]/picture?type=normal

```
<?php
$tumblog = 'natadec0c0'; // change to your username
// if your Tumblog is self hosted, you need to change the base url to the location of your tumblog
$baseurl = 'http://' . $tumblog . '.tumblr.com';
$request = $baseurl . '/api/read/json';
$ci = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($ci,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$input = curl_exec($ci);
curl_close($ci);

// Tumblr JSON doesn't come in standard form, some str replace needed

$input = str_replace('var tumblr_api_read = ','',$input);
$input = str_replace(';','',$input);

// parameter 'true' is necessary for output as PHP array

$value = json_decode($input,true);
$content =  $value['posts'];
$blogInfo = $value['tumblelog'];

// the number of items you want to display
$item = 10;

// Echo the blog info
echo "<h3><a href=\"" . $baseurl . "\">" . $blogInfo['title'] . "</a></h3>\n";
echo "<h4>" . $blogInfo['picture'] . "</h4>\n<hr />\n";

?>
```

how to append my current avatar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to use

```
GET http://www.tumblr.com/api/authenticate?email=user@example.com&password=12345
```

to get the avatar of the user. The sample response for mine is

```
<tumblr version="1.0">
<user default-post-format="html" can-upload-audio="1" can-upload-aiff="1" can-ask-question="1" can-upload-video="1" max-video-bytes-uploaded="26214400" liked-post-count="134"/>
<tumblelog title="ABNKKPGPiCTuReNPLaKo?!" is-admin="1" posts="301" twitter-enabled="0" draft-count="0" messages-count="0" queue-count="" name="arvn" url="http://arvn.tumblr.com/" type="public" followers="17" avatar-url="http://28.media.tumblr.com/avatar_b1786ec9e62d_128.png" is-primary="yes" backup-post-limit="30000"/>
<tumblelog title="i kras yu." is-admin="1" posts="1" twitter-enabled="0" draft-count="0" messages-count="0" queue-count="" name="ikrasyu" url="http://ikrasyu.tumblr.com/" type="public" followers="2" avatar-url="http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_02a7ef66fce8_128.png" backup-post-limit="30000"/>
</tumblr>
```

and get the `avatar-url` field of the corresponding tumblelog. Too bad there is no json format option, maybe use preg_match. You also need the email address and password of the user, or do it via [OAuth](http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps).

Or you could scrape the tumblelog for the avatar.

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://{$tumblog}.tumblr.com/");
$avatar = preg_match('/<img src="(http.+)" alt="portrait"/', $page, $matches) ? $matches[1]: 'http://example.com/blank.png';
```

Comment: thank you for sir, but about without OAuth? amm just like this site http://www.tumbletrain.com try to add your tumblr username.. then refresh the page it will automatically add your tumblr photo... how did it done? sir :)

Comment: @marc Best bet would be that they fetch the tumblelog page and look for this `<img src="AVATAR_URL" alt="portrait"`. Try to add a tumblelog that does not display their avatar on the home page.

Comment: @marc I edited my answer to add that option; scraping the page

Comment: owhhh whew, i will this bro.. :) wait a second.. :)

Comment: @alvin owhh yahh, haha sorry i forgot, :)im just new here @ stackoverflow ;) btw bro pinoy ka pala.. :) whew, pwde hingi ng ym mo bro? ;)

Answer (score 7):

A better solution for this is to put the Avatar api in an img tag.

```
api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/avatar[/size]

example: <img src='http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myreallycoolblog.tumblr.com/avatar/48'/>
```

So as long as you have the blogname, you can display the avatar.

Comment: For me I had to include `/blog/`, aka `<img src='http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myreallycoolblog.tumblr.com/avatar/48'/>`